# Chart.js lost its colors

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am making a chart on a site and I found chart.js to produce a chart from a json-file.
Everything works but the colors... the three chart is three grey colors and I want to spice it up...

What have I missed?

```
   var ctx = document.getElementById('speedchart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ti,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Latency',
      data: lt,
      fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1.0)"
    }, {
      label: 'Up speed',
      data: up,
      strokeColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.4)"

   }, {
      label: 'Down speed',
      data: dw,
      strokeColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.4)"

   }]
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example with e.g. codepen?

Comment: Heres that: http://codepen.io/macmattias/pen/LxBqBg

Comment: No idea if the code works in codepen, it seems like not since I read stuff from my local fs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are mixing chart.js 1.x syntax with chart.js 2.x

Dont think strokeColor is a valid option in chart.js 2.x.

Here is an example of how you can add some color.

```
[{
   label: 'Info',
   backgroundColor: "rgba(46, 44, 211, 0.2)",
   borderColor: "rgba(46, 44, 211, 0.5)",
   data: data
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brqc0tmw/4/

For more options look at the documentation
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-dataset-structure

Comment: That is correct I was using the v 1 syntax for a v 2 project, thank you!